# Touchable view react native isn't very responsive

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

i'm building a react native app and i found that Touchable view in react native is not responsive. It needs some time to see the result when i touch the button.

When i googling the solution, i found in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html that the solution is wrap any in `requestAnimationFrame` . When i do like what the link said, it show me error "`this.requestAnimationFrame` is not a function"

any example to use requestAnimationFrame in react-native?

here's some of my code what i've done so far:

```js
createBookingPage(){
        latestSender = bookings[0].from_name + " " + bookings[0].from_phone 
                        + " " + bookings[0].from_address;
        this.props.navigator.push({id: 4, latestSender, savedEmail, savedPassword});
      },

createBookingPage(){
        this.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this._createBookingPage();
        });
      },
        
    render(){
      return (<View>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.createButton}
                underlayColor='#ff7043' onPress={this.createBookingPage}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: 'white'}}>+</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>);}
```

Comment: in your onpress bind this.

Comment: do you mean `this.createBookingPage.bind(this)`? nah, it still not much responsive

Comment: Have you run this on your device with the product set to 'release' ?

Comment: well it worked, I tried to change schema to 'release' and it more responsive then before.  I wonder why in 'debug' scheme isn't so responsive than in 'release'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your main Navigator page customize your scene configuration for navigating through views like this:

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid;

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
 //A very tightly wound spring will make this transition fast
 springTension: 80,
 springFriction: 0,
  //Use our custom gesture defined above
  gestures:{

 }
});



class Photoos_net extends Component {
constructor(props, context){
 super(props, context);
 this._configureScene = this._configureScene.bind(this);

 }

 render() {
   return (
     <Navigator
      initialRoute= {{id: 'Home' , component: 'Home' , index:0}}
      renderScene = {this.renderScene.bind(this)}
      statusBarBackgroundColor={'royalblue'}
      configureScene={this._configureScene}
     />

 );
}

 _configureScene(route){
    return CustomSceneConfig;
  }
```

Now your transition will be quite faster than before.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why we can get benefit from `configureScene`? thanks

Comment: we can customize our transition effect through configureScene, since configureScene is the inbuilt method of Navigator component. We can disable gestures transition, somehow speed up transition/navigation speed, can insert different effects like fading, floating etc. with the help of configuring Scene.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to add some configurations like yours and it become quite faster. Also, thank you for explaining `configureScene`.